# Multiple xml feeds, sql match

Tags: php, mysql, xml, feed

I'm developing a store which gets its product info from lots of xml feed, I'll have maybe 3000 products in my database. I'll do it using a cronjob.

What I'd like to do is write posts, lets say a general post about picking the best TV set for yor family. Then I'd make a mysql match whitch should take the posts title and content and match it to the thousands of products in my database and retrieve the closest match to display on my post.

I'm thinking of this becouse having alot of xml with different nods, categories would be very hard for me to propely filter them using php.

1. Now, do you think thats a good ideea? content, performace wise?
2. Do you think mysql match could do it? Maybe use some other method?
3. Should I store all the product info like price, description, reviews in a single table field and use it for the mysql match?
4. Is there a better way I can do this?

Any ideea is very appreciated, I need to sort this out, make a plan before I start coding and waiting time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is awful with pure XML.

I strongly suggest you to leave this task to your Database in this case MySQL, basically your 3rd point.

With MyISAM table you can set up the full text search if you need a bit more complex query based on affinity.